# Personal webpage set in https without my interaction. How to undo it?

Tags: https, host

i've got a little problème im not even abble to clearly formulate.
And this didnt helped me finding an answer on the internet.

So I rely on you people if somehow you have allready encouter this problem or either simply had an idea of where this could came from.

***Here is my problem :*** When I try to connect on my personal website the navigator (Chrome or Firefox, haven't test with others) told me the certificate of security is invalid and is only valid for ssl1.ovh.net (ovh is my web hosting-provider).
The error code is : **ssl_error_bad_cert_domain**.

Well if any of you has an idea of where this could came from ?

Here is my website if some wants to have a look : *maelmayon.fr*

Thank you for reading it, I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is not a solution to the underlying problem, this is a nice workaround.

Either add a security exception in your browser, or explicitly link via `http://`. The security violation report should only show when trying to connect via `https://`.
I think you'd have to contact your provider for a shared SSL certificate to enable connection via `https`